What to do if ollama downloads big model and gets error resetting connection?
enter image description here
I'm using macos.
When I ran ollama run llama3 in the terminal and got the following error：
pulling manifest 
Error: pull model manifest: Get "https://ollama.com/token?nonce=8UU-FvbYyGTesdUePHqRqQ&scope=repository%!A(MISSING)library%!F(MISSING)llama3%!A(MISSING)pull&service=ollama.com&ts=1714116326": read tcp 172.17.12.43:50708->34.120.132.20:443: read: connection reset by peer

How do I fix it?
I tried turning off the firewall and it didn't work too.

Have you found a solution?  I am facing a similar issue with error: Error: llama runner process has terminated: signal: abort trap error:error loading model architecture: unknown model architecture: 'gemma2'

Update Ollama and this issue will be resolved
